# Error:gradle project sync completed with error

Tags: java, android

i got this error when i open my project,gradle project sync with errors.open message to view the error found,and when i try downloading the update,i also get this error: tag mismatch,nothing downloaded;
error code: Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
>   Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.+.
>        Versions that do not match:
>            24.0.0-alpha2
>            24.0.0-alpha1
>            23.3.0
>            23.2.1
>            23.2.0
>            + 16 more
>        Searched in the following locations:
>            file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio2/gradle/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml
>            file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio2/gradle/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/
>            file:/C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml
>            file:/C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml
>            file:/C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/
>        Required by:
>            JustJava2:app:unspecified

Comment: put your gradle file here

Comment: "open message to view the error found" - what you mean? you should take more care about grammar, because your question is very hard to read.

Comment: luiz what am saying saying is that i get this error when ever i launch my Android studio

Answer (score 0):

Delete the ".gradle" file as shown the below image path [Service Directory path].

Restart the studio. It will load the newly required files.

Normally gradle sync issue happens when when you upgrade the studio but not the updated libraries which are working in the project.

[image: Android Gradle Sync Faile]

Comment: Go to preferences from your android project to get the above screen.

Comment: i dont have preferences on my andriod studio am using,android studio 2,1.2